# inserting text into textarea with jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

Almost noob with Javascript/Jquery here.  I'm building a relatively simple email form which I would like to populate with one of a few pre-defined templates stored in a MySQL database, retrieved with PHP.

The select pulldown menu is built from the database entries (Description), and on the user changing it, should load the subject and body into the appropriately named fields.

I've had success with using PHP to build javascript if statements on page load to compare against the select menu, and it does load the subject into the text field.  When trying to load a textarea, the entire script fails.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#Template').on('change',function(){
    var Template = $(this).val();
<?php
$emailQuery = "SELECT RecID,Subject,Body FROM ST_Email ORDER BY Sort ASC";
$emailResults = mysqli_query($connect, $emailQuery);
while ($ERow = mysqli_fetch_array($emailResults))
{
$RecID = $ERow['RecID'];
$EmailContents = addslashes($ERow['Body']);
$Subject = $ERow['Subject'];
echo "if (Template == $RecID)
{
    $(\"#Subject\").val(\"$Subject\");
    $(\"#EmailContents\").val(\"$EmailContents\");
}
";
}
?>
    });
});
</script>
```

Later, in the HTML/PHP...

```
echo "<p>Please choose an email template from this pulldown menu:</p>
<p><select name=\"Template\" id=\"Template\"><option>-- Blank --</option>";
$emailTemplateQuery = "SELECT RecID,Description FROM ST_Email ORDER BY Sort ASC";
$emailTemplateResult = mysqli_query($connect, $emailTemplateQuery);
while ($ETRow = mysqli_fetch_array($emailTemplateResult))
{
    $Description = stripslashes($ETRow['Description']);
    $RecID = $ETRow['RecID'];
    echo "<option value=\"$RecID\">$Description</option>";
}
echo "</select></p>";
?>
Subject line: <input type="text" name="Subject" size="94" id="Subject" />
<p>Contents of message:</p>
<p><textarea name="EmailContents" rows="26" cols="94" id="EmailContents"></textarea>
<input type="submit" name="Send Email" value="Send Email"/>
```

Naturally, the contents of $EmailContents will include line breaks, some special punctuation, and a lot of text.  I did initially try to do this with AJAX and JSON, but couldn't get anything to happen with that.

From what I've read the .val(foo) method should work for textareas, but it doesn't work for me.  I'm expecting the user to choose an email template and doctor the text up and then submit the form.

Would greatly appreciate any and all assistance.  I've learned a lot from the other Stack Overflow questions and answers, but this one has me stumped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is very crafty, but looks fine to me. I do however have an idea what lines are breaking it.

```
$(\"#Subject\").val(\"$Subject\");
$(\"#EmailContents\").val(\"$EmailContents\");
```

Imagine you had an email template with the following content:

> Hello"

Now if this content got inserted to your JavaScript via PHP, it would break out of the `val()` function, because it's ending the string parameter:

```
$(\"#EmailContents\").val(\"Hello"");
```

To confirm that this is the problem, open up the developer console and under the "sources" tab open your JS file to see if that's what's causing it.

Comment: Thanks very much for this.  I didn't find any quotes within the database content, but found line breaks and carriage returns were breaking the code.

Now off to try to figure out how to change this so it will work...